# Graphql subscriptions fails with Redis implementation

Tags: graphql-subscriptions

I have an application composed of two parts: a React frontend which makes use of [graphql-subscriptions](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions) and a Node.js app with [an MQTT broker](https://github.com/mcollina/aedes) (and its web socket handler) and [a subscription server](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws).
[As stated here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-subscriptions/external-pubsub.html), instead of using the default `PubSub` implementation (which is working), I'm trying to implement an external PubSub Engine and for this, I chose [graphql-redis-subscriptions](https://github.com/davidyaha/graphql-redis-subscriptions).
Whenever a message is reaching the server, I get the following error:

```
2018-03-27 14:52:03: assert.js:42
throw new errors.AssertionError({
   ^
 AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: undefined == true
   at MQEmitterRedis.emit (node_modules/mqemitter/mqemitter.js:98:3)
   at handler (node_modules/mqemitter-redis/mqemitter-redis.js:36:12)
   at Redis.<anonymous> (node_modules/mqemitter-redis/mqemitter-redis.js:46:5)
   at emitThree (events.js:136:13)
   at Redis.emit (events.js:217:7)
   at Redis.exports.returnReply ( node_modules/ioredis/lib/redis/parser.js:119:14)
   at JavascriptRedisParser.returnReply ( node_modules/ioredis/lib/redis/parser.js:27:13)
   at JavascriptRedisParser.execute ( node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:574:12)
   at Socket.<anonymous> ( node_modules/ioredis/lib/redis/event_handler.js:107:22)
   at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
   at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
   at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
   at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
   at TCP.onread (net.js:594:20)
```

I cannot understand what's going on here. [By looking at the code, it seems that this assert is failing because the argument is undefined](https://github.com/mcollina/mqemitter/blob/master/mqemitter.js#L98). 
Here is the configuration of `PubSub.js` file, which is imported when it's necessary to publish something:

```js
import { RedisPubSub } from 'graphql-redis-subscriptions';
import config from '../config/getConfig';

const { port, host } = config.redisConf;

// Options listed here: https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/master/API.md#new_Redis_new
const pubsub = new RedisPubSub({
    connection: {
        host,
        port,
        retry_strategy: options => Math.max(options.attempt * 100, 3000),
    },
});

export default pubsub;
```

then, in another file, I just import `import pubSub from '../../helpers/PubSub';` and I use the following code to publish on a topic:

```js
pubSub.publish(topic, { operation: { ... }});
```

Could you suggest if I'm doing something wrong? 
Thanks